# Stop Nginx from auto-starting on Mac. Port conflict on port 80, using LocalWp / Local By Flywheel

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I have an application (LocalWp or Local By Flywheel), that uses nginx to run on localhost.
Whenever I reboot my machine, Nginx starts back up and thereafter LocalWp starts up, but hits a port conflict, since Nginx is already running on port 80.

[The solution](https://localwp.com/community/t/is-there-a-fix-for-the-port-conflict-problem-local-5/17843/5?u=zeth) is to exit LocalWp, run `sudo nginx -s stop` and start LocalWp back up.

But I have to do this every time I reboot my machine, I have to do this.

How do I stop Nginx from starting up, whenever I boot?

---

### Bonus info

I initially had a running apache-server running as well, but I only had to stop that once, doing this: `sudo apachectl stop`

[Find more info here](https://localwp.com/community/t/resolving-port-conflict-with-this-sites-domain/23562)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run: `sudo brew services stop nginx`

... But only if you have Nginx installed via Brew.
You can find more informationer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352070/how-do-i-prevent-nginx-from-auto-loading-using-homebrew).